# Credit Card Verification Number Fails

Tags: civievent

Running CiviCRM 4.6.3 with Drupal 7.38.  In CiviEvent I am not able to get any 3 digit card verification number to pass the test payment processor in Test-drive or Live.  Using 4111 1111 1111 1111 as the test card number.  Continue to receive "Please enter a valid Card Verification Number".

Comment: I haven't seen this issue running a similar setup - and it's the sort of thing that if it were a universal problem, we'd know VERY quickly!  Could you say more about if it ever worked, and then stopped working?  What payment processor are you using?

Comment: Thank you Jon G.  I have never been able to get card verification to work.  I started out a couple of weeks ago using the CiviCRM Test Payment Processor.  Card verification didn't work.  About 4 days ago I added the Stripe.com extension (yes, I know it is not certified on 4.6.3) and card verification does not work on that either.  I have a long standing account on Stripe (two actually) and the Stripe Payment Processor is configured correctly as far as I can tell.  But then it is not a Stripe issue since it wasn't working before Stripe.

Answer (score 2):

Bert, based on the error message you report, I think your validation failure is in the three digit **card verification number** (CVV), not the card number (PAN). Normally I use 111 as CVV for the 4111 test card.

Answer (score 2):

And the answer is... It appears the bone head admin forgot to enable any credit cards (Visa, MasterCard, etc).  Once the credit cards where enabled card verification (CVV) worked as advertised.  Thanks everyone! -Bert (Site Admin)

Answer (score 1):

If the issue really is with the PAN, try that same test card number but without the spaces, and let us know if that works?

The payment forms *ought to* handle stripping those out in [`civicrm_billingblock_creditcard_helper()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Core/BillingBlock.js), but it's possible they don't, or they don't specifically for Stripe (eg if the Stripe processor intercepts the form submit clientside before the aforementioned function has completed).

CiviCRM uses (at least) clientside JS to strip spaces out; if that JS doesn't fire for some reason (perhaps local JS issues, or Stripe gets there first) AND CiviCRM doesn't handle it serverside, then you *might* see behaviour like that with the PAN.

I would expect Stripe's API to cope fine with spaces. Are you seeing the validation error within CiviCRM?